# Loop returns only the last item

Tags: ruby, loops

I'm new to Ruby, so the answer is probably pretty simple. Not to me though

I am taking an array of strings (A) and matching it against another array of strings (B) to see if a given string from (A) exists as a substring within a string from B.

The compare seems to work however, I only get back a result from the last (A) string compared.

What might this be?

```
def checkIfAvailableOnline(film)

    puts "Looking for " + film
    lowerCaseFilm = film.downcase

    #iterate through the linesarray scanning for the film in question

    for line in @linesArray
        #get the line in lowercase
        lowerCaseLine = line.downcase

        #look for the film name as a substring within the line
        results = lowerCaseLine.scan(lowerCaseFilm)

        if results.length > 0 
            @availableOnlineArray << results
        end
    end

end
#-----------------------------------------

listFilmsArray.each {|line| checkIfAvailableOnline(line)}
```

Comment: Some test code could help. How did you test your code?

Answer (score 1):

Given a list of film names:

```
FILM_NAMES = [
  'Baked Blue Tomatoes',
  'Fried Yellow Tomatoes',
  'The thing that ate my homework',
  'In a world where',
]
```

Then to find all film names containing a substring, ignoring case:

```
def find_films_available_online(partial_film_name)
  FILM_NAMES.find_all do |film_name|
    film_name.downcase[partial_film_name.downcase]
  end
end

p find_films_available_online('tomatoes')
# => ["Baked Blue Tomatoes", "Fried Yellow Tomatoes"]

p find_films_available_online('godzooka')
# => []
```

To find out if a film name is available online:

```
def available_online?(partial_film_name)
  !find_films_available_online(partial_film_name).empty?
end

p available_online?('potatoes')   # => false
p available_online?('A World')    # => true
```

To find out which of a list of partial film names are available online:

```
def partial_film_names_available_online(partial_film_names)
  partial_film_names.find_all do |partial_film_name|
    available_online?(partial_film_name)
  end
end

p partial_film_names_available_online [
    'tomatoes',
    'potatoes',
    'A World',
  ]
# => ["tomatoes", "A World"]
```

Answer (score 0):

A more rubyish way to do this is:

Given an array of films we are looking for:

```
@films = ["how to train your dragon", "kung fu panda", "avatar"]
```

Given an array of lines that may contain the films we are looking for:

```
@lines_array = ["just in kung fu panda", "available soon how to train your dragon"]
```

Return the film name early if it exists in a line or false if it doesn't after searching all the lines:

```
def online_available(film)
  @lines_array.each do |l|
    l.downcase.include?(film) ? (return film) : false
  end
  false
end
```

Check for the films in the lines rejecting the ones that returned false, print them and ultimately return an array of the matches we found:

```
def films_available
  available = @films.collect{ |x| p "Looking for: #{x}"; online_available(x) }
                    .reject{ |x| x == false }
  available.each{|x| p "Found: #{x}"}
  available
end
```

It is considered bad style to use camel-case in method names with Ruby but you know what they say about opinions.

.each is an internal iterator and I'm pretty sure the "for" loop will run slower than the enumerable each method that arrays inherit.

Comment: `each` is faster than `for` in ruby 1.9.1, but slower in ruby 1.8.7.  The differences, though, are not significant, the body of the loop invariable taking many orders of magnitude more time than the looping mechanism.